# No valid model identifier for Django fixture data?

Tags: python, django, fixtures

I'm sure there's a simple answer here but I can't see it. I'm trying to load fixtures into my database but no matter what model identifier I use I keep getting the `DeserializationError: invalid model identifier:...` error.

File structure:

```
testproject/
    testapp/
        fixtures/
            data.json
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    sqlite3.db
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Since this is my first go at fixtures, I'm using the model from http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/fixtures/:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Default headline')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

data.json:

```
[
    {
        "pk": "3",
        "model": "testapp.article",
        "fields":
        {
            "headline": "Time to reform copyright",
            "pub_date": "2006-06-16 13:00:00"   
        }
    }, 
    {    
        "pk": "2",
        "model": "testapp.article",
        "fields":
        {
            "headline": "Poker has no place on ESPN",
            "pub_date": "2006-06-16 12:00:00"
        }
    }, 
    {    
        "pk": "1", 
        "model": "testapp.article",
        "fields":
        {
            "headline": "Python program becomes self aware",
            "pub_date": "2006-06-16 11:00:00"
        }
    }
]
```

I've tried `testapp.article`, `testproject.article`, `testproject.testapp.article` and they all throw the same error. I'm running 1.2.4 with Python 2.6 and using loaddata rather than syncdb. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that app.modelclass is the right format. Did tou try to dumpdata to see what is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data.json file is fine, I have tried it and it works.

are you sure your db is synced with your models?

what do you run to load the file?

as Luc suggested, compare the "manage.py dumpdata testapp" output with your file

Comment: I would second the recommendation to check your models against the actual database. django may base the model identifiers off what's in your database, not what's in your models.

Comment: & @David Antaramian: Yep, db wasnt's synced correctly with the models. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try check settings.py, in my case i just forget add app in INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will even help at all, but I'm currently looking at some fixtures I have written and all my model identifiers are properly cased.

Here's an example from my user accounts fixture, but note that it's in YAML.

```
- model: auth.User
  pk: 4
  fields:
    username: avirtue
    first_name: Aurora
    last_name: Virtue
    is_active: true
    is_superuser: false
    is_staff: false
    password: sha1$90431$9347d343e94122f94f9f02988f026a76d339ab02
    email: avirtue@someschool.edu

- model: users.UserProfile
  pk: 4
  fields:
    user: 4
    school_id: 420985
    professor: false
```

This is in a file under the folder users/fixtures/ (that is, there is an application users, and this file is located in that application's fixtures folder).

As you can see, the models are actually coming from two different locations. The second one I use is from the same application and defines a `UserProfile`. The first one is actually from the `django.contrib.auth` module, which the project uses for authentication.

Comment: I noticed the different case between "Article" (in models.py) and "article" in (data.json) but that's not a problem. I verified it using postgres and sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same error "Invalid model identifier" several times and what I always realized is that it either am using a wrong app name or the app name is wrongly spelled. That is "model": "testapp.article", the testapp is either wrongly spelled or expect a different app name not testapp as of the case above.